# should I delete VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I've just downloaded and started to use VS community 2013, and up to now, I'm quite impressed with it.  I also have VS 2012 professional on my machine, and I'm getting little short of space on my hard drive.  Would you suggest removing VS2012, and is it safe to do so?

Answer (score -1):

If you have no legal / license issues with the fact to use "Community" rather than "Professional" license, AND if you don't have coworkers using strictly VS2012 I think you could reasonably uninstall VS2012.

For my second assumption, 2013 is pretty "retro compatible" with 2012, but it's better to keep homogeneous environments between developers.

I think the uninstall itself should go very well (so far never had issues myself with that kind of things, even with CTP or RC releases), but if you are afraid you can do a restoration point or some kind of backup of system before uninstall.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, there's no point anymore in switching to VS 2013, because VS 2015 RTM will soon be available - it is currently in CTP 6 and you can get it for free.

The great thing about VS 2015 - apart from all the new features like e.g. C# 6.0 support - is that you get the full version for free, not just a community edition with reduced functionality.

Comment: Sorry but not fully agree with you : since VS2015 is only in CTP6 (very recently released!) we don't know when the RTM will occur but we can be sure it won't happen in next weeks, and as the OP has already installed VS2013 he could stick to this release for the time.

Comment: Are you a project manager at Microsoft? And who is 'we'? And: There's almost no difference between VS 2012 and VS 2013 - but there's a gigantic one between VS 2013 and VS 2015.

Comment: It looks like we don't answer to the same question. OP doesn't want to know if VS2015 will be a great IDE when it will be available or if it's interessant to buy 2013 (of course it's not), he wants to know if he can safely switch to VS2013, as he have already installed it and he can do it freely NOW, because he runs out of disk space.